# Gmail API blocks external <img> sources

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm developing an integration with Gmail API and PHP to send emails from my clients account vinculated with Gmail.

The problem is that Gmail is blocking all external images in message body (I want to track whenever sent email is opened by destinatary).

Example:
`<img src="http://my_domain.com/track_opening.php?GUID=XXXXX">` is replaced by `<img>` when the email is sent.

How can I track an email open when that message was sent using Gmail API?

Thanks!

Comment: We don't do "RESOLVED" or "SOLVED" in titles here if you've found the answer to your question. You can post an answer an accept it, or delete the question. On a side note I learned a new word today -- vinculated

Comment: Then, both of us have learned something today.

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

to

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8-bit
```

resolved the issue.